# Prerequisites for rigorous Fourier analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, fourier-analysis

My side project for 2021 is to get a grasp for Fourier analysis. At first I thought that perhaps I should take an application heavy approach and do the heavy math later on. But the more I dwell deeper into the subject I find myself needing proper rigorous proofs and reasoning for the material I am presented.

As Fourier analysis seems to rely heavily upon both measure theory and functional analysis, what books/material would **you** recommend to work on in order to build a solid & rigid foundations in both measure theory and functional analysis? Books and the material should preferably be self-contained. Bonus points if the book/material has been going around long enough, so that I can find discussion regarding the practice problems - mega bonus points if the material happens to have a solution manual.

Currently my plan is to first go through both baby Rudin and Ahlfors (*Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Walter Rudin, *Comples Analysis*, Lars Ahlfors) in order to check that I don't have any serious holes in my understanding of real and complex analysis. From there I was planning to use *Functional Analysis* by Rudin as my primary source of functional analysis, and a yet undecided book for measure theory. I am also happy to takes notes and comments on this *general* study plan!

Comment: Quick question: Are you familiar with the Laplace Transform?

Comment: Fourier analysis is a career itself, however you can get a grasp of it in 1-2 months reading some of the many textbooks about the topic that there are. Many of these textbooks are self-contained so you don't need any prerequisite beyond a first course in real analysis

Comment: I'm also trying to understand Fourier analysis during summer time. What I've taken away is that it's a very vast field. The absolute authoritative books on it are Classical and modern Fourier analysis by Loukas Grafakos. As for the theoretical analysis, yeah I'd recommend going through baby rudin and spend time on anything you don't understand, (Ahlfors complex analysis is much more than what's required. It's actually a graduate complex analysis text book). Then, I'd recommend reading the first chapters of classical Fourier analysis.

Comment: ... Rudin's functional analysis is more like a third or fourth book on Functional analysis and is a very difficult text. His real and complex analysis book and his functional analysis book are actually used as a reference book and they are both super difficult texts. Honestly don't waste your summer torturing yourself. From your comments I would actually recommend you go through baby rudin to fill any holes and then read Folland's Real analysis. It has a lot of exposition to Fourier, measure theory, functional analysis and is an excellent text for actually getting some breadth of analysis.

Comment: @imranfat Can't say that I really am. Laplace has appeared few times in various courses, but I haven't had any serious discussion regarding it.

Comment: @Masacroso Fair enough. Let me rephrase the question into: "Do you know a good source material for Fourier Analysis which actually proves the claims it makes?" There are probably gigabytes worth of reading material for Fourier Analysis, but all of the introductory material I have seen so far brush off the (in my opinion) important proofs, which I would like to understand. Application wise this is perhaps the least efficient way of studying (any) the subject, but I keep getting annoyed not knowing why the claims hold.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the tip on Folland! Would you use Folland's Real Analysis to study measure theory, or do you happen to know some other book for that? Moreover do you have a take on a good book for complex analysis?

Comment: @Epsilon you can try the introductory book of Stein & Shakarchi about Fourier analysis, or maybe the introductory book of harmonic analysis of Deitmar. All books about Fourier analysis that I had read contain full proofs. Folland is really hard to read IMHO, I will avoid it at your level, its at the level of Rudin hard books (or more)

Comment: I actually study for probability and so I tend to focus on material that's somehow applicable to that. Measure theory (at least the foundations) itself can be very dry and abstract and it's difficult to appreciate it before doing math that needs it. I recommend Folland for getting a mature perspective on the analysis field which I think you might be missing. A friendlier book than Rudin which I have skimmed through is Measure, Integration and real analysis by Sheldon Axler. Read all chapters and spend time doing exercises. You could read relevant chapters of folland for further interest.

Comment: ... Tldr my advive: Read all of Axler's measure, integration and real analysis and make sure you understand everything. Then see what "interests" you and read the relevant chapters from the plethora of books mentioned to see what's there and actually focus more on understanding what the theorems mean regardless of how well you may understand the proofs.

Comment: As for complex analysis: for the basics up to calculus of residue and contour integration any undergrad textbook is great as long as you solve exercises, books are all the same. Then it gets really hard. The definitive text is Ahlfors bit it's more like a six months grad course. And from there it gets research level super specialised where it can get mixed with geometry, number theory, probability, etc. So, all the stuff you mentioned are their own fields and people spend decades making a career out of them. First "learn" the foundations really well. And, then you can "read what interests" you